# Careers profile timeout

Tags: support, jobs

A while ago I used to let my careers profile opened for hours in edit mode. When I refreshed the page, it was still refreshing correctly.

Recently, after logging in (using my gmail account), if I leave it for 15 minutes or so, after refreshing, I have to relogin. Did anything change in the session timeout rules or similar?

Comment: It's rather something have changed on _your_ side during the 15 minutes.

Comment: I experience similar behavior indeed. I constantly keep having to log in to my Careers profile